# Retrieve and parse JSON data from PHP Webservice to XCODE iPhone App

Tags: php, xcode, json, web-services

This is my webservice in php running in my host.

```
<?php  
    $data = array("T1","T2","T3","T4","T5");
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

And this is the xcode snippet.

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:myDinUrl];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

If Y execute the url in my web browser y get:

```
["T1","T2","T3","T4","T5"]
```

But the Xcode Output always shows `urlData` as a empty object `(0x000000000)` if I show the error description I see a `Operation couldn't be completed code=256`

If I use another URL like: [Url1](http://ielmo.xtreemhost.com/array.php) or [Url1](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/270074/iosTutrials/JSON/Test.json) the `NSData` object get some bytes that can be formatted and parsed.

Comment: please paste ur MyDinUrl code and also is NSURL * url is a typo error? It should be like NSURL *url

Answer (score 0):

Since your PHP encodes the response in JSON, you have to parse it expecting a JSON-encoded response.

NSJSONSerialization can do this for you, but it requires NSArray or NSDictionary (that means you must change your NSData declaration to either one of these.)